# How to query android contact title

Tags: android, contacts

It's possible in android 5.x and above by using append extra part to content provider like this:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contactsandroid.provider.extra.ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX=true&directory=0.
```

Then It's return a List of section like [A,B,C,D...Z.#]. or In Korean language Env [ㄱ,ㄴ,ㄷ,ㄹ,..ㅎ].

But how to do it in 4.x? Is there any lib to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution. When query use
`uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX, "true").build()` in android 5.x and above and use `uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("address_book_index_extras", "true").build()` above 4.x and below 5.x.
Then get these property like this:

```
private int[] getIndexTitleCounts(Bundle bundle) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return bundle.getIntArray(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_COUNTS);
    } else {
        return bundle.getIntArray("address_book_index_counts");
    }
}

private String[] getIndexTitles(Bundle bundle) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return bundle.getStringArray(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_TITLES);
    } else {
        return bundle.getStringArray("address_book_index_titles");
    }
}
```

enjoy